# One Big Application vs Multiple Small Applications in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, architecture, apache-kafka

I am new to software development. Currently I am doing a project which collects REAL TIME data from a sensor installed in different locations. Each sensor will send data to the server every minute. In future I am expecting 100k sensors sending data to the server every minute. Currently I am doing the following.

1. TCP Listener in the server made on Node.js
2. Putting received data to the queue
3. Validating the data and pushing it to database

Now I need to implement a lot other business logic like sending an SMS or email when the sensor data exceeds preset value. Detect if something bad is happening like different types of real time processing.

I am thinking of writing separate Node.js application for different types of data processing, like below.

1. TCP Listner (same as above)
2. Putting received data to queue (same as above)
3. Validating data and pushing to database. (same as above). If some kind of data processing is required for this sensor, I am planning to put it to ANOTHER QUEUE
4. Separate application for processing this new QUEUE

So I am expecting another 4 separate application and QUEUE for implementing special real time data processing.

- Queue : Apache Kafka
- Database : Cassandra

Am I going in the right way or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs is single thread model, in your case mostly work is processing message which needs cpu cycle. So writing separate Node.js application is better if message arrive rate is high.

And if your message has many types and each process logic only need to process its own interested message type, then create different topic for different message type, and every process only subscribe its interested topic. It will be faster and more elegant.

But if your process application need to process all the message, you could use different consumer group to subscribe one topic, and do not need to put same message to other queue.

Anyway, I think one thread to do one thing or one app to do one thing is a good design.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting data to queue (2.) before validating them (3.) - don't you want to first validate data, then push them to queue before process them (depend of what is validating)?

Otherwise, this is an ok scenario. If you haven't already, I would advise you reading some introduction to [kafka streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) and its concept, which is how stream processing is done natively by kafka (the implementation is in java only for the moment, but there seems to be an unofficial nodejs port in-going [here](https://github.com/nodefluent/kafka-streams) )

Without speaking of kafka stream, you could also directly send from sensor to kafka, rather than having a server (this allow you to not have to worry about replication, distribution, what happen if your server crash...) There are kakfa producer and consumer in nodejs (https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka and https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node are two good clients) and almost all languages. All sensors could send data to the same topic, or to different topics if the data are not related at all.

The good thing about having multiple application for processing, relying on the same kafka queue, is that each treatment is independant : you won't break one by modifying the other, you can evolve them separatly, etc

You can also use [kafka connect](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-the-perfect-match/) to read from the validated data topic and write to cassandra directly - you only need to do some conf, no java required here

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your suggestion. 
I am getting data from sensors in bare TCP packets (I cannot change it). I am doing a basic validation in the first step. That TCP packets is containing different data. I am validating individual data after the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misinterpreting your steps 1-3 but it should be enough to do just 1 and 2. Once data is successfully committed into Kafka you can use Kafka Connect to send copies to Cassandra and your Database. Perhaps that's what you mean by #3 but if not then there is no need for a separate write from your nodejs app directly to the database since Kafka can do this.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. Actually I am getting bare TCP packets from sensors. There are a lots of parts in the data. So I need to do some processing in the received data before inserting to database. That is why I am using node.js in the step 3. I am not sure whether same is possible with Kafka Connect.

Comment: You can use one of the nodejs Kafka clients to publish the data to Kafka after to process it. Your other options would be to use one kafka-connect-tcp Connector or something like node-red which can take incoming tcp and send outgoing Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Use different consumer groups subscribed to single topic.so you need  a producer which listens to your requests and put data in kafka topic and consumers in different consumer groups , which does different things.